# Add animate in toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

```
$scrollTop = $('.scrollToTop');
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    $('.scrollToTop').toggleClass('active', $(window).scrollTop() > 0);
});
```

I was try animate effect via CSS but working:

```
.scrollToTop {  transition: all 2s linear;}
```

And via jQuery:

```
 $('.scrollToTop').toggleClass('active',1000, $(window).scrollTop() > 0);
```

But it is same, not working.

How can I add animate in my toggleClass structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something Like

```
$('#review-link').click(function(e) {
    $('.new_comment').toggle();
    // $('.comments').toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){

       $(this).text('Exit review mode');
       scrollToAnchor('.comments');
       return false;

    }else{

        $(this).text('Enter review mode');
        $('body').animate({scrollTop: 0},'slow');
        return false;
    }
});
```

[Demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/tAQYf/17/)

[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/cMJZ4/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the jQuery UI extension of `.toggleClass()` to enable animate - I'm assuming that you're using the normal jQuery version. Check out the docs here:

http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleclass/